# custom updating multiple documents in mongoose corresponding to given ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have schema something like this

```
 var betDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 { 
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  value: { type: Object, required: true },
  _id : {type: String, required: true}
 },
 { timestamps: true, _id: false }
 );
```

I want to update the value field in all the document  in a manner

query all the document at once by _id
and update the matching _id with the matching _id document provided
if the matching _id document does not exist than create a new one

i tried to write the code

```
    BetDataModel.updateMany({
         // filters
      name: 'listEventTypes',
      _id: { $in: newarr.map(x => x._id) }
    },

     // new documents to be updated on the existing document
    [doc1, doc2, doc3],

    // if not present create a new one
     {upsert: true, new: true}
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to re-produce minimal environment, here's a script I came up with:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const shortid = require("shortid");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test9999", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", async function() {
    await mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();

    var betDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        value: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        _id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        _id: false
    });

    const BetDataModel = mongoose.model("BetDataModel", betDataSchema);

    const b1 = new BetDataModel({
        name: "Pop",
        value: {
            x: 5
        },
        _id: "ID1"
    });
    const b2 = new BetDataModel({
        name: "Rock",
        value: {
            x: 5
        },
        _id: "ID2"
    });
    const b3 = new BetDataModel({
        name: "Rock22",
        value: {
            x: 5
        },
        _id: "ID3"
    });

    await b1.save();
    await b2.save();
    await b3.save();

    newarr = [new BetDataModel({
        _id: 'ID2',
        value: {
            x: 10
        },
        name: "Newid2"
    }), new BetDataModel({
        _id: 'ID4',
        value: {
            x: 11
        },
        name: "Newid44"
    })];

    bulk = BetDataModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    for (i in newarr) {
        var doc = newarr[i];
        bulk.find({
            _id: doc._id /* additional filters here */
        }).upsert().update({
            $set: {
                name: doc.name,
                value: doc.value
            }
        }, {
            multi: true
        });
    }
    await bulk.execute();


    await BetDataModel.find(function(err, bets) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(bets);
    });
});
```

The `updateMany` idea is a right direction, but you have to provide a literal while preparing `updateMany` query, as far as I am concerned. In your case, you want to dynamically iterate over a list and prepare a `bulk` query. So, I believe in my example this is gonna translate to multiple UPDATE statements, but will be done in a single query.

This part is most relevant:

```
bulk = BetDataModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
for (i in newarr) {
    var doc = newarr[i];
    bulk.find({
        _id: doc._id /* additional filters here */
    }).upsert().update({
        $set: {
            name: doc.name,
            value: doc.value
        }
    }, {
        multi: true
    });
}
await bulk.execute();
```

In my case, it code yields the following:

```
[ { _id: 'ID1',
    name: 'Pop',
    value: { x: 5 },
    createdAt: 2020-08-25T08:58:59.335Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-08-25T08:58:59.335Z,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 'ID2',
    name: 'Newid2',
    value: { x: 10 },
    createdAt: 2020-08-25T08:58:59.359Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-08-25T08:58:59.359Z,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 'ID3',
    name: 'Rock22',
    value: { x: 5 },
    createdAt: 2020-08-25T08:58:59.361Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-08-25T08:58:59.361Z,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 'ID4', name: 'Newid44', value: { x: 11 } } ]
```

upserted record is missing timestamp information, but I'm sure you can handle this.